# Trouble getting document with \documentclass{aa} to compile

Tags: errors, compiling, document-classes, compilation-error

I am having trouble running this [Example of a manuscript header with structured abstract](https://www.aanda.org/for-authors/latex-issues/latex-examples) which the journal of Astronomy and Astrophysics provides on their webpage. I have downloaded the "A&A LaTeX macro package" which they provide [on their website](https://www.aanda.org/for-authors), and put all files into the document folder.

When I copy-paste the above example into a tex-file, and try to typeset, I first get an error that there would be too many `}`. After deleting the one which looks too much I get the error/message:

> IMPORTANT
>
> Class aa Warning: The running head built automatically from \author and \titlee xceeds the pagewidth, please supply a shorter form with \authorrunning and/or \titlerunning prior to \maketitle on input line 48.
>
> IMPORTANT
>
> (\usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/t1txtt.fd))
> *

I am not sure what that means, and I did not find anything relevant when googling for that error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: The message seems to be a warning (and not an error), suggesting that you use the `\authorrunning` and/or `\titlerunning` commands to supply a shorter form of the authors and/or title, that will fit in the page header.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the reply! Yes, I suppose you are right, thanks! I now found another way to get a template compiled: Their macro package contains a file named aa.dem. I guess .dem stands for demonstration, since it is basically an example template code. Renaming this file to .tex dies the trick, and it compiles straight away.

Comment: As answered by @Ma

Answer (score 0):

Just to be more clear on what @Marijn answered. \authorrruunning{} and \titlerunning{} commands have to be included right before \maketitle. This is explained in the [A&A accueil page](https://www.aanda.org/65-author-information/information-files).

```
\titlerunning{short title}
\authorrunning{name(s) of author(s)}
```